# Reset array for file upload

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

The attachments keeps getting the previous file selected. If i selected 3 files, and then re-select again 2 files, the total files becomes 5 not 2. The attachments keeps adding up the files before and not reset when i want to re-select. Thanks in advance.

**Template**

```
<input id="upload-file" type="file" multiple class="form-control" @change="fieldChange">
```

**Script**

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
          year:'',
          attachments:[],
          form: new FormData
        }
    },
    methods:{
        fieldChange(e){
            let selectedFiles=e.target.files;
            if(!selectedFiles.length){
                return false;
            }
            for(let i=0;i<selectedFiles.length;i++){
                this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
            }
            console.log(this.attachments);
        },
   }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Also facing issues is that after submitting the form. The form.pics[] still has the previous files and when submit the previous files will be saved again in the database. I tried to reset it with form.pics = [] but doesn't work.

**Script**

```
 uploadFile(){
            for(let i=0; i<this.attachments.length;i++){
                this.form.append('pics[]',this.attachments[i]);
            }
            this.form.append('year',this.year);
            axios.post('/api/gallery',this.form).then(response=>{
                console.log(response);
                this.form.pics = [];
            })
            .catch(response=>{
                //error
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are pushing to the attachments and did not reset it.

Try this

```html
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
          year:'',
          attachments:[],
          form: new FormData
        }
    },
    methods:{
        fieldChange(e){
            this.attachments = []; // added this one
            let selectedFiles=e.target.files;
            if(!selectedFiles.length){
                return false;
            }
            for(let i=0;i<selectedFiles.length;i++){
                this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
            }
            console.log(this.attachments);
        },
   }
</script>
```

Comment: works perfectly, mind having a look at my new problem. I edited the post. thanks

Comment: this.form.pics won't work because this.form isn't an Object. It's adviced not to declare `new FormData` in data. Try to declare `const form = new FormData` in the `fieldChange` methods

Comment: @HelloWorld1014 if this answer help remember to accept this as the solution. Thanks!